# Base change of discrete series

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $\pi_f$ be an automorphic representation of $GL_2(A_Q)$ (attached to a modular form $f$), and suppose we want to look at its base change lift to say a quadratic imaginary field. Which are the representations at the infinity places of such form?

The question merely refers to what is the "base change lifting" of a discrete series of $GL_2(R)$ to $GL_2(C)$, since $GL_2(C)$ does not have such representations (but the base change should be special in some sence).

Comment: Ignoring (at some small peril) the distinction between $SL$ and $GL$: this ought to be a purely local question that could be answered by looking at the relevant theta/Segal-Shale-Weil/oscillator correspondence $O(3,1)\times SL_2(\mathbb R)$. ($SL_2(\mathbb C)$ is the spin group over $SO(3,1)$.)